# Integral Separation of disjoint submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, limit-cycles

Assume that $M_1, M_2, \ldots , M_k$  are  $k$ disjoint  compact  submanifolds  of  $\mathbb{R}^n$ of  the  same  dimension $m$. Assume that $\lambda_{ij}, \; 1\leq i,j\leq k$  are  $k^2$ arbitrary  real numbers.

> Are there  $k$ differential $m$- forms $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_k$ with $\int_{M_{i}} \alpha_{j}= \lambda{ij}$?

The  motivation for this post is that a  positive  answer to the  above  question implies that
the  number  of  closed orbits  of  a planar vector  field $X$ is  less than the  codimension of the  range of  the  following  linear  operator:

$$L_X:\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2)\to  \Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2) $$

Because  if  $\gamma$  is  a  closed orbit  of  $X$ then for  every $\alpha  \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$  we have $$\int_{\gamma} L_{X}\alpha  =0 $$

Now if $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_n$  are  closed orbits  of  $X$ and we  have  $n$  elements $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n$ of  $\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that the  matrix $(\int_{\gamma_{i}} \alpha_{j})_{i,j}$  is  an invertible  matrix, then no  nontrivial linear  combination $\sum c_i \alpha_{i}$ belongs to the  image  of  the  operator  $L_{X}$.  This  shows that the codimension of the  range  of  $L_X$ is  more  than the  number of  closed orbits.

Comment: Erm... what prevents you from interpolating any forms you want on small neighborhoods of the manifolds?

Comment: @fedja  thank you for your idea. What about the holomorphic case.  Disjoint compact  holomirphic curve in certain complex projective space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for integration of differential forms to make sense, we need $M_1,\dotsc,M_k$ to be oriented. Let $\omega_i\in\Omega^m(M_i)$ be such that $\int_{M_i}\omega_i = 1$.

Since $M_1,\dotsc,M_k$ are pairwise disjoint, compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, then they have open neighborhoods $U_1\supset M_1,\dotsc, U_k\supset M_k$ such that the $U_i$s are pairwise disjoint (see [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575640)). Let $h_i$ be a smooth function supported in $U_i$ and equal to 1 on $M_i$; it's [a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Existence_of_bump_functions) that these functions exist.

The $\alpha_j$ in question is
$$\alpha_j := \sum_{\ell=1}^k \lambda_{\ell j} h_\ell\omega_\ell.$$

When restricted to $M_i$, $h_i = 1$ and $h_j = 0$ if $j\ne i$, so $\alpha_j|_{M_i} = \lambda_{ij}\omega_i$ and
$$\int_{M_i} \alpha_j = \lambda_{ij}.$$