# Conjugacy of $L_X$ operators

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, differential-operators

Assume that $X$ is a vector field on a $n$ dimensional manifold $M$.Let  $0\leq i,j \leq n$.

1.Is there a linear isomorphism $T:\Omega^i(M) \to \Omega^j(M)$ with $L_X T=T L_X$?

2.Is there a linear isomorphism $T:\Omega^i(M)/Z^i(M) \to \Omega^j(M)/Z^j(M)$  with $TL_X=L_XT$?

By $Z^i(M)$ we mean the space of closed differential $i$_form.

For a motivation please see the following post:

[Fredholm index vs. Limit cycle theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269855/fredholm-index-vs-limit-cycle-theory)

Comment: The spaces you consider need not be isomorphic, so in general, this answer is no.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig  What  is  a  precise example  of this  non isomorphicity?

Answer (score 1):

For appropriate choices of $i$, $j$ (e.g. $i+j \neq n$), $\Omega^i(M)$ and $\Omega^j(M)$ have different ranks as $C^\infty(M)$ module, so at least they cannot be isomorphic as modules. Maybe they could be isomorphic as topological vector spaces, but I don't see why, and in any case, this would not be very natural.

If you choose $i=j$, then of course $T = \mathrm{id}$ works.

More generally, setting $T= \psi_t^*$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ does the job, where $\psi_t$ is the flow of $X$, and $\psi_t^*$ denotes pullback via the flow.

Comment: @MittihasLudewig  (+1) and thank you  for  your  answers to my  questions.  I  think that it is  natural  to compare  $\Omega^{i}(M)$  and  $\Omega^{j}(M)$  as  two  vector  spaces not  two  modules, since $L_{X}$ is  not a  $C^{\infty}(M))$-linear operator.