# A cubic system with two nested limit cycles with opposite orientations

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, limit-cycles

What is  an example  of  polynomial vector  field  $$\begin{cases} x'=P(x,y)\\ y'=Q(x,y) \end{cases}$$  such that two closed orbits $C_1,C_2$ of the system surrounds  an annular  region $R$ such that $R$ does  not contain any  singular point and the flow orientation of $C_1$  is opposite  to the  flow-orientation of  $C_2$.

The  motivation for this  question is the  following [counterexample  of  a  nongeodesible flow on the  torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273689#273689) and [the  following post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Note that this  situation can not be  occurred  when the  degree of  $P,Q$ is at most $2$. See theorem $4$ [of the  following paper.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039666900702).So we  search  for  a  cubic (or  higher degree ) system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not hard to concoct such an example in sufficiently high degree.  For an example of degree $5$, take
$$
\begin{align}
x' &= x\,(1-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2-3) - y\,(2-x^2-y^2)\\
y' &= y\,(1-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2-3) + x\,(2-x^2-y^2).
\end{align}
$$
The circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=3$ are integral curves of this vector field with opposite orientations.  The only zero of the vector field is at the origin $(x,y) = (0,0)$.  In the annulus $1 < x^2+y^2 < 3$, the flow always increases $x^2+y^2$ and it moves in the counterclockwise direction when $1 < x^2+y^2 < 2$  but in the clockwise direction when $2 < x^2+y^2 < 3$.

I don't know whether there is a system of degree 3 or 4 that has such a property, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: That is  a  very  interesting  example Thank  you very much  for that.This  example  and  your  counterexample to  the  recent  question  of Terry  Tao were really  a very great  help  for  me.

Comment: Thank you again for  your  answer to this  question. What  about  higher dimensional foliation: For  example  is  it  trivial to ask "Is  the Reeb  foliation, geodesible" in the  sense that there is  a  metric  on $S^3$ such that all leaves  are totally  geodesics?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: There is no metric $g$ on $S^3$ for which the all the leaves of some codimension 1 foliation $\mathcal{F}$ of $S^3$ are even minimal, let alone totally geodesic. The reason is that, for such a pair $(g,\mathcal{F})$, the leaves can be oriented by a unit normal vector field $N$.  Then the $2$-form $\Omega = \iota(N)\bigl(\mathrm{vol}(g)\bigr)$ would be closed (since the leaves are minimal) and hence exact.  But by Novikov, $\mathcal{F}$ must have a compact leaf $L$, and the integral of $\Omega$ over $L$ would have to be positive.  But by Stokes' Theorem, this integral must be zero.

Comment: I've seen something similar to this flow at the airport. Look at the separation curves between sectors:       https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baggage_carousel#/media/File:Baggage_reclaim_hahn_airport.jpg