# Limit cycles as closed geodesics(2)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, open-problems, limit-cycles

Hilbert 16th problem asks  for  a  uniform upper  bound  $H(n)$  for  the number of  limit  cycles  of  a  polynomial  vector  field  of   degree $n$  on the  plane. Here is an updated proof of the finitness part of the Hilbert 16th problem:

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=8352&option_lang=eng

This  problem is  open even for  $n=2$.

In this  question, by  a  quadratic  vector  field  we mean a polynomial  vector  field $$P(x,y)\partial_x+Q(x,y) \partial_y\;\;\;(V)$$  where  $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ are  polynomials  of  degree 2  with $P(0,0)=Q(0,0)=0$.

So  the  question is  that

**(Hilbert  16th problem  for  n=2)     Is $H(2)$ a  finite number?**

As a possible  approach to this  question we would  like to  look at limit  cycles  of  a  vector  field as  closed  geodesics. Namely we would  like  to put  a  Riemannian metric on the (regular part of the )  phase space  such that the trajectories  of  the  vector  field would  be  unparametrized geodesics. By  regular  part  we  mean the  complement  of  singularities  of the  vector  field. Thus  each limit  cycle  would be a closed  geodesic. Then using  Gauss Bonnete theorem we try to count the number of closed geodesics. So the  sign of  the  Gaussian curvature play a  very  important role.  But the  first  problem is that, regardless of  the  curvature sign, is there a  Riemannian metric on the  regular  part of  the  phase space such that the  trajectories  of the  vector  field would be  geodesic.

[This example  shows](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273970/a-cubic-system-with-two-nested-limit-cycles-with-opposite-orientations?noredirect=1&lq=1) that,  for a  polynomial vector  field of  arbitrary  degree such metric  does not  necessarily existed.  But  for  quadratic  vector  field the  situation is  different as  follows.
In the following   $C$ is  the  algebraic  curve $$yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)=0\;\;\;\;\;(C)$$

> **Observation:** There is  a  Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ such that all solutions  of  **Quadratic  vector  field**  $(V)$ are  geodesics. Furthermore every  limit  cycle of  $(V) $  which  surround the  origin can not intersect the  curve  $C$

The  proof  of  this  observation is  based  on Proposition 6.7  and  6.8    as  follows:

[Geometry  of  foliation](https://books.google.com/books?id=8DZZSsa14ncC&pg=PA71)

So  we are sure  that, on the complement of  the  above  algebraic  curve  $C$,  we  have a Riemanian  metric such that all  solutions  of  $(V)$ are  geodesics.

The  methods  of  the proof  of  the  Propositions  [6.7  and  6.8 in the book Geometry  of  foliation](https://books.google.com/books?id=8DZZSsa14ncC&pg=PA71)
suggest  that we  choose a  Riemannian  metric whose  orthonormal base is  the following:

$$\left\{\frac{x^2+y^2}{yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)}V,\ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}W\right\}.$$

where $V=P\partial_x +Q\partial_y$ is  the  quadratic  vector  field as in $(V)$ and  $W$ is the radial  vector  field $W=x\partial_x+y\partial_y$. In fact $W$, as it is  required  in the  proof of  the  above  two propositions,  lies in the  kernel of  $1\_$ form $\psi=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(ydx-xdy)$.  This  $1\_$ form is  very  essential to  apply propositions 6.7 and  6.8 in the  above  reference. In fact  this is  a  closed form which is identically equal to $1$  on the  first  vector of the above orthonormal frame.That is $\psi(\frac{x^2+y^2}{yP-xQ}(V))=1$.

I  am really  indebted to  Ben McKay who  suggested the  $1\_$form $d\theta$ as  a  required $1\_$ form for  possible  satisfactions  of proposition 6.8.

On the other hand  the  method  of  the proof  of  the  Proposition 6.7 shows  that,  on the  complement of
$C$, all trajectories  of  $V$ are geodesics for the metric  arising from the  above orthonormal frame. **Moreover we are free to  rescale  the second  vector  of the  frame, arbitrarily**.

Now  the  main problem is that we  control the  sign of the  curvature  of  such  metric to make facilities to  count the  number  of  closed  geodesics. In fact  we  use  the  Gauss  Bonnete theorem.

Call the curvature of this metric $\kappa$.

> Question: When a quadratic vector field $V$ does not have a center on the  plane, is the curve $$\{(x,y)\mid \kappa(x,y)=0\}$$ transverse to $V$?
>
> If not, what appropriate  rescaling of the the second vector $ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} W$ of the orthonormal frame would give a positive answer?

Notes:

1)A center is a singularity which is surrounded by a band of closed orbits. For  quadratic vector fields they are classified at [this  paper.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246484433_Integrability_of_plane_quadratic_vector_fields)

2)**Of course existence of  a  positive  answer to this  question implies that $H(2)$ is  finite.** Because the  number of  limit  cycles  of $V$ which  suround the origin can  be uniformly  bounded since $\kappa=0$ is  an  algebraic  curve so in every  connected  component of this  algebraic  curve, we  have  at  most on limit  cycle  surrounding origin.
On the  other  hand there are at  most  2  nest of  limit  cycles. So this would  imply that $H(2)<\infty$

The  motivation for this post is mentioned in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648) and [this post.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space)

However   the initial motivation is mentioned in [page 3, item 5 of  this  arxiv note.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507516)

Comment: @Matt F. Thank you very much for your edit.