# Computer algebra for calculating curvature when the tensor metric is very big

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-algebra

Is there a  computer  algebra  method  to  compute  the  curvature of  a  Riemannian metric  on the  plane when the metric  tensor has  long entries $E,F,G$

The  computation by hand is  very complicated and  long.

I  would  like  to  apply this  possible  software to calculate the  Gaussian curvature described in the  following posts:

[A curvature description for center condition for quadratic vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277481/a-curvature-description-for-center-condition-for-quadratic-vector-field/278766#278766)

[Limit cycles as closed geodesics(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277495/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics2)

[Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648)

I computed by  hand,  [for  two  particular  vector  fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277481/a-curvature-description-for-center-condition-for-quadratic-vector-field/278766#278766)

$V=y\partial_x-x\partial_y$  and $V=y\partial_x -(x+x^2)\partial_y$

Now  I need  try  other  vector  fields so  I  need  computer help.

Thank you for  your  help, comments  or  answers.

Comment: I've never used it, but there's this: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/

Comment: @DeaneYang  Thanks.  very  nice site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try SageManifolds http://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/

See this example  (there are several others) for how to compute the curvature tensor from the metric

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/sagemanifolds/SageManifolds/blob/master/Worksheets/v1.0/SM_Schwarzschild.ipynb

*Hint*: it's just

```
R = g.riemann()
R.display()
```

**EDIT**: Here's a complete example

You can open the CoCalc worksheet here:

https://cocalc.com/app#projects/38691bca-4290-4f77-a3b0-bee86df3d85f/files/sagemanifold.sagews

```
M = Manifold(2, 'M', r'\mathbb{R}^2')
coords.<x,y> = M.chart()
g = M.riemannian_metric('g', latex_name=r'g')

E(x, y) = e^(x + y)
F(x, y) = e^(x^2 + y^2)
G(x, y) = e^(x + y)

g[0, 0] = E
g[0, 1] = F
g[1, 1] = G

R = g.riemann()

R.display()
```

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for your  very  interesting answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is some Maple code at

https://github.com/NeilStrickland/genus2/blob/master/maple/embedded/curvature.mpl

It is a fairly straightforward translation of the definitions.  I am not clear whether that is what you need.  If not, perhaps you could be more specific.

Comment: Thank you so  much for this  codes. I try to apply these.