# An isocline geodesic characterization of $2$ dimensional flat metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Lets we have  a  Riemannian metric on an open subset of the plane which satisfies the  following local property.

**Local Property:**  For  every point $x$ and every foliation by geodesics around  $x$,  there exist a  geodesic $\alpha$ passing $x$ which is locally transverse to the foliation and is  an  isocline, that is its  angle  with leaves it intersect is a constant(independent of  leaves intersected by $\alpha$).

> Does  this  local property imply that  the metric is necessarily a flat metric?

**The motivation:**  For the moment assume that all $2$ dimensional Riemannian metric satisfy this local property. Then the  answer to the  question ["Limit cycles  as closed geodesics"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space) would be negative, that is, we  would  not be able to  count a  limit cycle as a  closed geodesic of  a  negatively curved space.

**The argument:** Assume that we  have  a  Riemannian metric with negative curvature compatible  to  a  vector  field $X$, that is all orbits  of  $X$ are  unparametrized geodesics for  the Riemanian metric. Assume that  $\gamma$ is  a limit cycle of $X$. We  choose a  point $x\in \gamma$ and an isocline  geodesic $\alpha$ passing $x$ as a  local section(local transversal section). We choose a point $y\in \alpha$ different from $x$. We denote by $p$ the Poincare return map associated to the limit cycle which is  defined on $\alpha$. Consider the simple  closed curve starting $y$ moving along the orbit of the vector  field passing $p(y)$ then joining $p(y)$ to $y$ via isocline $\alpha$. Then applying the Gauss Bonnet theorem we obviously get a contradiction. In fact the isocline property enable us to consider $\gamma '$ as a smooth closed geodesic whose interior contain another clised geodesic $\gamma$. So it is obvious that a negatively curved space in the plane can not posses two nested closed geodesic.

Since I can not drow a picture I use the following picture:
I mean that, in the following picture,if the $x$ axis is an isocline geodesic and the curvature is negative then the geodesic in the picture which is spirali g can not surround a closed geodesic. It can not be contained in a closed geodesic, too:

https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Limit_cycle_Poincare_map.svg

In fact the matter is that the Gauss Bonnet formula for the sum of angles of a $n$-polygon is valid for a $2$ polygon. We used this fact in the above argument. Our $2$-polygon has $2$ edges. The first edge the flow-orbit starting $x$ and ending $p(x)$. The second edge is a sub segment of isocline $\alpha$ starting $p(x)$ and ending at $x$.

**Note:** Of course the local property of this  question is  satisfied by the Euclidean metric  and  does  not  satisfied by the  Hyperbolic  metric on the  upper  half plane  with vertical  foliation.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Even the Euclidean metric in the plane doesn't have this property.  Look at the foliation $\mathcal{F}$ consisting of lines through the origin $O$ and let $x$ be any point other than the origin.  Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a foliation of a neighborhood of $x$ for which no such 'isocline' geodesic $\alpha$ exists.  In fact, no metric could have this property:  The set of geodesics $\alpha$ through $x$ is a 1-dimensional family, and, for any such geodesic $\alpha$, there is only a 1-dimensional family of geodesic folliations that meet $\alpha$ at a constant angle.

Comment: @RobertBryant  I  am  sorry that my  question was incorrect. Thanks  for  your  comment which help me to realize my  mistake. on the  other hand your  valuable comment  help me to be  calm that this  "local property",  which does not exist at all, is  not  an  obstruction for   consideration of  limit cycles as  closed geodesic of  a  negatively or  positively  curved space.

Comment: @RobertBryant  But  there  exist another  possible  obstruction. It is  possible  that a  particular geodesic  foliation admits  such isocline transversal.

Comment: @RobertBryant  I  would  appreciate if you  consider  this  particular case. Assume that $P(x,y),Q(x,y)$ are quadratic polynomials  with real  coefficients. We  consider  the  foliation associated to the  vector  field $P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$.(We remove the  algebraic  curve $yP-xQ=0$ ). Now  we consider the  Riemannian metric associated to the  frame $\left\{\frac{x^2+y^2}{yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)}V,\ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}W\right\}.$ (or a  possible  rescaling of the  second  vector of this frame). The  foliation is  adapted  to the metric.Is this particular foliation satisfies  that  local property?

Comment: The  motivation for  such a  frame  is  written in this  post:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277495/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics2

Comment: As I explained in my first comment, *every* embedded geodesic $\alpha$ on a Riemannian surface is an 'isocline transversal' of a $1$-parameter family of geodesic foliations; you just need to specify the constant angle that it makes.  There's nothing special about these, except that, for the flat metric, this only generates a 1-parameter family of geodesic foliations that admit 'isoclines'.  For most metrics, this generates a 3-parameter family of (local) geodesic foliations, but I don't see how they would be useful for your problem.

Comment: @RobertBryant  I understand you fox a geodesic $\alpha$ then you inteoduce a folition by geodesics for which $\alpha$ is an isocline transversal. But in my previous comment I am considering the reverse situation: I fix a foliation then I ask for existence of Local isocline transversal. As your example showed the radial foliation does not admit such isocline transversal.  So the situatio  depends on the foliation we initially fix. So my question is the following:We fix the foliation associated to a quadratic vector field. We also fix the metric we introduced with that frame. So ..

Comment: ...so we have a foliation by geodesics. Now our question is that : for a given point $x$, is there an isocline geodesic passing x. If the answer would be yes, the above frame(and corresponding metric) is not a godd candidate for the idea of consideration of limit cycles as closed geodesocs in a negatively curved space. May be I am missing some thing to understand your previous comment?

Comment: @RobertBryant  to be honest I  do  not  understand how does "3 parameter" family arise?May I ask you to explain on it?Moreover could I clarify my question in the previous  2 comments?Is the question in my previous comment has a  similar mistake  as my question in my intiall post?

Comment: Here's an example:  Consider the hyperbolic plane $H$ (i.e., $K\equiv-1$). Given an oriented geodesic $\alpha$ and angle $\theta\in(0,\pi)$, there is a unique foliation $\mathcal{F}_(\alpha,\theta)$ of $H$ whose leaves are the oriented geodesics that meet $\alpha$ in an angle of $\theta$. If $\mathcal{F}_(\alpha,\theta)=\mathcal{F}_(\beta,\psi)$, then $\alpha=\beta$ and $\theta=\psi$ (up to orientation and some 'signs').  Thus, this is a $3$-parameter family of geodesic foliations of $H$ (since geodesics depend on $2$ parameters).  This holds for the generic suitably convex Riemannian surface.

Comment: @RobertBryant  But my question is  some what different. In your  previous  comments  you fix a  geodesic  and  you introduce a (several parameter)geodesic foliation for which the initial geodesic  is  an isocline. But after your  first comment I am considering a  new  version of  my question: We fix  a  foliation by geodesics(In our case this the  quadratic  system for  which the frame described above is  a  compatible metric. Then we ask:"is it true to say for  every x in the phase space($\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$, there exist  a  local isocline  geodesic passing  $x$. If t the answer is posit

Comment: positive  then we  can not hope that  the  sign curvature is  constant.

Comment: @RobertBryant  I think that I just understand  what you  hinted me; For  a  given geodesic $\alpha$  there is  a (3 parameter) geodesic foliation for which $\alpha$ is  an isolcline. On the other hand, for  a  given $x$ there  is  a  one parameter family of  geodesics passing $x$. so we have  totally 4 parameter family of  geodesics which works  for  our purpose. Am I  right? If yes how  can we apply this situation to our case?

Comment: @RobertBryant  based on your very helpful comments I tried to correct the  concept in this new post. then I  mentioned the motivation  for  consideration of  "isocline" i would  appreciate if  you read this new version. thank you for your attention.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302009/some-possible-obstructions-to-limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics3