# (Some possible obstructions to ) Limit cycles as closed geodesics(3)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, limit-cycles, closed-geodesic

First we  explain our  Motivation:

**Motivation:**

> First note that there is  no  a  Riemannian metric  on an open set  of  the  plane  which possess two  nested closed geodesics $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ and the  curvature in the  annular region made by these two closed geodesics has constant sign(either positive or  negative).
>
> But the same  is  true if we keep the  closed geodesic $\gamma_1$, the innermost one,  and replace the  smooth closed geodesic  $\gamma_2$, the outermost one, by a  non smooth one  denoted again by  $\gamma_2$ provided $\angle p+\angle q =2\pi$. (Please see the  figure bellow). In fact $\gamma_2$ is the  union of two pieces of  geodesics whose union make a simple closed curve which can be  counted as a 2-polygon(with two vertex $p,q$), whose sum angles is $2\pi$, look at the following    figure(Note that the  horizontal axis  is  assumed to be  a  geodesic  as well as  other curves in the figure> Furthermore it is  obvious that by  "angle"  we  mean  Riemannian  angle, that is  the angles $\angle p$  and  $\angle q$  are Riemannian angles  not the  Euclidean angle drown in the picture ):

[image: GaussBonnete]

> In the  above  figure all curves are assumed  to be  geodesics including the  (horizontal) $x$-axis.
>
> On the other  hand, [in this   question, Limit Cycles  as  closed Geodesics(2),](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277495/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics2?noredirect=1&lq=1) we  had intention to  consider limit cycles  of  a  quadratic  vector  field as closed geodesic. Our  approach is  based on usage of Gauss  Bonnete theorem so the  sign of  Gauss  curvature  play a  crucial role. So we observe that certain "Isocline -type  property" of  foliation by  geodesics could  be  an  obstruction for Looking at limit cycles as  closed geodesics in a  negatively curved space.  We explain this  "Isocline- type property" in the  main part of  our  question

**Main part of our  question:**

Let $M$  be  a  Riemannian surface with  a  foliation $\mathcal{F}$ whose  leaves  are  geodesics. We say that $\mathcal{F}$ has the local isocline property if for  every $x\in M$ there exist  a  geodesic $\alpha$ passing $x$ which is locally transverse to the foliation and intersects the leaves of the foliation with a  fix angel. We call such a  geodesic  $\alpha$ an isocline.

Let  $X=P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$ be a quadratic polynomial vector  field on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Define the algebraic curve $C=\left\{(x,y)\mid yP-xQ=0\right\}$. Let $W$ be a vector field proportional to $x\partial_x+y\partial_y$.

Associated to the above quadratic vector field, we consider the  Riemannian metric on $M=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$ whose orthonormal frame is the following: 
$$\left\{\frac{x^2+y^2}{yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)}V,\ W\right\}.$$

Then all orbit  of the  vector  field  are  geodesic of  the  metric  with the above frame. So  we have  a  foliation by geodesics  $\mathcal{F}$ on the  Riemannian surface $M$.

> Question: Is there an example  of  such situation with the  above Local isocline property? As a more general question: Is it true to say that every  foliation associated to a  quadratic  vector  field necessarily satisfies the  above  local property? (A possible positive  answer to the latter two questions is  an obstruction for  consideration of  limit  cycles  as  closed geodesics in negatively or  positively curved space.)   But if the  answer is  "No", can we choose  an  appropriate $W$ in the  above  frame  such that this local property fail at all point  $x\in M= \mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$?

**Note 1:**  The  above  definition of "Isocline  Local property" is  a  corrected version of  the  following post:

[An isocline geodesic characterization of $2$ dimensional flat metrics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301200/an-isocline-geodesic-characterization-of-2-dimensional-flat-metrics?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Note 2:** With the same argument as the materials of this  post one can prove the following obvious observation:

**Obvious Fact:**

There is  no a  conformal Riemannian metric on the  punctured plane with non vanishing curvature with the following two properties:

1) The  orbits  of the  solutions  of the  Van der Pol equation $$\begin{cases}x'=y-(x^3-x)\\ y'=-x \end{cases}$$ are unparametrized geodesics.(Foliation by geodesics)

2)The positive $y$-axis  is a  geodesic.

Please  see this  MO  question as  a  related post: [Limit cycles as closed geodesics(in negatively or positively curved space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Just a naive comment : have you thought about interpreting limit cycles as the trajectory of a free particle describing a geodesic on a Riemannian manifold moving slowly in some ambient space ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN  Thank you for  your  attention. Could  you please  more  explain on your  comment. It would be interesting to consider  a  physical interpretation for this problem.

Comment: It's just an analogy that may or may not be relevant to you problem. Imagine an ant on Earth going straight ahead from the north pole along the Greenwich meridian till it reaches the south pole, then goes on along the 180° meridian back to north pole at constant speed and there stops. For an observer on Earth the trajectory of the ant is a closed curve. For an observer standing on the Sun, it's not, as the position of the north pole has changed while the Earth revolves our star.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN  your physical approach remind me of two titles which I found many years ago in the web as follows: "Is quantum mechanics a limit cycle theory?" And "Limit cycles in quantum theories". To be honest I do not have a physical background to underestand physical interpretations for limit cycle theiry.  Thanks for your attention to my question.