# Two questions on "foliation by geodesics"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

I  would  appreciate if you  consider the following two  questions on $1$ dimensional  foliations whose leaves  are  geodesic.

1)Assume that $M$  is  a Riemannian manifold which is  either an open manifold or  is  a  compact  manifold  with  zero  Euler  characteristic. Does $M$ admit a  foliation by  geodesics?

2)Assume that $M$ is  a  Riemannian surface which admit at least one  foliation by  geodesics.
Does there necessarily exist a  foliation of $M$ by  geodesics which satisfy the "Isocline  Locale  property"?

The  [Isocline  local property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302009/some-possible-obstructions-to-limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics3) is defined as follows:

For  every $x\in M$ there is locally  a  geodesic  $\alpha $  which is  transverse to the foliation and it intersect all leaves with the same  angle.

Answer (score 7):

No to the first question. Let $M$ be a Riemannian $2$-manifold whose universal cover is the hyperbolic plane $H$, and whose fundamental group is not cyclic. For any foliation of $H$ by geodesics (lines), it seems to me that the endpoints of these lines on the boundary circle of $H$ will fill up the whole circle except for two points. These two points will have to be preserved by deck transformations, so any discrete group of isometries of $H$ that preserves the foliation must be cyclic.

Comment: But for these surfaces the Euler characteristic is not zero (which is indeed a necessary condition for a codimension 1 foliation, be it geodesic or not).

Comment: @Thiku: The $M$ in this answer is an open manifold.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say choose it to be open, for example the sphere minus three points (with constant curvature metric).

Comment: To be honest I can not understand this  answer.  For example consider  $M=H\setminus \{p,q\}$. Then  is not  $H$ the  universal covering space of $M$? But M admit a  foliation by geodesic. The vertical foliation. Am I mistaken?

Comment: This $M$ is not complete, as it would have to be if its universal covering space were to be metrically isomorphic to $H$.