# A cubic system with two nested limit cycles with opposite orientations(2)

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, open-problems, counterexamples, limit-cycles

The second part of Hilbert's 16th problem not only concerns "The number of limit cycles of a polynomial vector field", but also the position and configuration of of those limit cycles with respect to each other.
However the primary and the usual interpretation of the concept "Relative Position" is that "Whether two given limit cycles are nested closed curves or not" but the following post is a motivation to consider other types of questions about configuration of limit cycles, for example  "Can two nested limit cycles have opposite orientation?"

[A cubic system with two nested limit cycles with opposite orientations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273970/a-cubic-system-with-two-nested-limit-cycles-with-opposite-orientations/274981#274981)

In this regard we focus on cubic polynomial system and ask the following question:

What is  an example  of **Cubic**  polynomial vector  field  $$\begin{cases} x'=P(x,y)\\ y'=Q(x,y) \end{cases}$$  such that two nested  closed orbits $C_1$, $C_2$ of the system surrounds  an annular  region $R$ such that $R$ does  not contain any  singular point and the flow orientation of $C_1$  is opposite  to the  flow-orientation of  $C_2$?

There is  a  very  interesting  example  of  degree $5$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273970/a-cubic-system-with-two-nested-limit-cycles-with-opposite-orientations/274981#274981) but  we search for  degree $3$

Comment: Is not in the example of degree 5 that you link to the origin a singular point?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Yes  but it does not  lie  in the  annular region between $C_1$ and  $C_2$. And this  is  what I  search for. Right?

Comment: Sorry I did misread the condition, thanks.

Comment: If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are concentric circles, $\dot x x+\dot y y=P(x,y)x+Q(x,y)y$ must vanish identically on $C_1$ and $C_2$, and on the origin. Doesn't this tell us that either P or Q has degree larger than 3?

Comment: @PietroMajer  Thanks for your comment. Yes that is true. But in my question we do not assume that our limit cycles are algebraic curves(eg. circles). In fact a generic polynomial vector field does not possess alfebraic solution.