# Is there a connection $\nabla$ for which this particular non geodesible vector field $X$ satisfy $\nabla_X X=0$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, connections

Let $X$  be  the  following  vector  field on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$
\begin{align}
x' &= x\,(1-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2-3) - y\,(2-x^2-y^2)\\
y' &= y\,(1-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2-3) + x\,(2-x^2-y^2).
\end{align}

[It is  well known that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273970/a-cubic-system-with-two-nested-limit-cycles-with-opposite-orientations/274981#274981) there is  no  a  Riemannian metric on the  punctured plane such that the  orbits  of  the  above  vector  field  would  be  unparametrized  geodesics.  [The  proof  is based on existence of  opposite orientation of  two consecutive nested  limit cycles in the phase portrait  of  the vector  field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273689#273689).

Now we  reduce the above  geodesibility requirement to the following  question;(Is this  an obvious reduced question)?

> Is there a (torsion free or metric or arbitrary)  connection $\nabla$  on the  punctured plane with $\nabla_X X=0$?

Comment: Are you asking for $X$ to satisfy $\nabla X = 0$ (as in the title) or $\nabla_X X = 0$ (as in the body---this is a weaker condition)?

Comment: @Travis  Thank you I revise the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector field can be written in polar coordinates as 
$$X=X^r\partial_r+X^{\varphi}\partial_{\varphi}=r(4r^2-r^4-3)\partial_r+(2-r^2)\partial_{\varphi},$$
which exhibits the rotational symmetry.
The condition $\nabla_X X=0$ implies that
\begin{align}
X^r\partial_rX^r+\Gamma^r_{rr}(X^r)^2+(\Gamma^r_{r\varphi}+\Gamma^r_{\varphi r}) X^rX^{\varphi}+\Gamma^r_{\varphi\varphi}(X^{\varphi})^2=0, \\
X^r\partial_rX^{\varphi}+\Gamma^{\varphi}_{rr}(X^r)^2+(\Gamma^{\varphi}_{r\varphi}+\Gamma^{\varphi}_{\varphi r}) X^rX^{\varphi}+\Gamma^{\varphi}_{\varphi\varphi}(X^{\varphi})^2=0.
\end{align}
For a connection with vanishing torsion, we have $\Gamma^r_{r\varphi}=\Gamma^r_{\varphi r}$ and $\Gamma^{\varphi}_{r\varphi}=\Gamma^{\varphi}_{\varphi r}$, which leads to the simplification
\begin{align}
X^r\partial_rX^r+\Gamma^r_{rr}(X^r)^2+2\Gamma^r_{r\varphi} X^rX^{\varphi}+\Gamma^r_{\varphi\varphi}(X^{\varphi})^2=0, \\
X^r\partial_rX^{\varphi}+\Gamma^{\varphi}_{rr}(X^r)^2+2\Gamma^{\varphi}_{r\varphi} X^rX^{\varphi}+\Gamma^{\varphi}_{\varphi\varphi}(X^{\varphi})^2=0.
\end{align}
Since the vector field has rotational symmetry, I will look for a connection with coefficients that depend only on $r$.
By making a fourth-order polynomial-in-$r$ ansatz for all Christoffel symbols,
$$\Gamma^i_{jk}=\sum_{m=0}^4\Gamma^i_{jkm}r^m,$$
one can find the following solution:
$$\Gamma^r_{rr}=-\frac{r}{2}, \quad \Gamma^r_{r\varphi}=\Gamma^r_{\varphi r}=\frac{1}{4}(3-12r^2+r^4), \quad \Gamma^r_{\varphi\varphi}=0,$$
$$\Gamma^{\varphi}_{rr}=2, \quad \Gamma^{\varphi}_{r\varphi}=\Gamma^{\varphi}_{\varphi r}=r(2-r^2), \quad \Gamma^{\varphi}_{\varphi\varphi}=0.$$

It's worth noting that anything lower than a fourth-order polynomial will not produce any solution.
There does not seem to be any other connection with polynomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank you  very  much for  your  answer. I  will learn its  details. BTW is it  a  metric  connection?

Comment: Wouldn't metricity contradict the non-geodesibility of the vector field?

Comment: Yes I am sorry for my stupid comment.

Comment: I don't think it is a stupid question. When you try to solve the equations $\nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}=0$ for the unknown metric, using the connection given above, a quick calculation seems to suggest (but I may have made a mistake, so I would suggest to try for yourself) that you can find a nontrivial solution in some finite disk, but not the entire punctured plane (the metric seems to become singular on the boundary of said disk). I did not study the proof of the non-geodesibility that you linked to, so I cannot vouch for its accuracy.