# The configuration of the zero locus of certain polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is  a complete description  for the configuration of  zero  locus of the  algebraic  curve  $C$ defined by  $$yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)=0$$

where  $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$  are  arbitrary polynomials  of  degree $2$.

What  is  the  (sharp) maximum number  of  connected  components of  $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$?

This  question is  motivated by "**EDITED**" part of  the following  answer:
[Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curve is a planar cubic, and such were classified completely recently by one Isaac Newton. An even more recent version can be found in this 1928 Annals of Math article:

```
Canonical Forms of Plane Cubic Curves Under Euclidean Transformations
R. S. Burington and H. K. Holt
Annals of Mathematics
Second Series, Vol. 30, No. 1/4 (1928 - 1929), pp. 52-60
```