# A curvature description for center condition for quadratic vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

We  consider  the  quadratic  vector  field  $V$  $$\begin{cases} x'=P(x,y)\\ y'=Q(x,y)
 \end {cases}\;\;\;\;(V)$$

where  $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ are polynomials  of  degree $2$ with $P(0,0)=Q(0,0)=0$.

We denote by $(W)$ the   linear radial vector  field $$W=x\partial_x+y\partial_y\;\;\;\;(W)$$

Consider the $1\_$form $$\psi=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(ydx-xdy)$$

Let  $C$  be  the  algebraic  curve $C=\{(x,y)\mid yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)=0\}$

We  consider  the  Riemannian  metric  on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$  whose  orthonormal frame is  the  following:$$\{V/\psi(V), W/(x^2+y^2)\}$$

For  such orthonormal frame, the  determinant of  the  corresponding tensor  metric $$\begin{pmatrix}E&F\\F&G \end{pmatrix}$$ is  identically $1$, that is  $EG-F^2=1$. Furthermore the  curvature is  zero for  the  linear  center $V=y\partial_x-x\partial_y$.

> Question: Is it true to say that $V$  has  a  center at origin if  and  only if the  Gaussian  curvature  of the  above  metric is  zero?

Note  that  a  center  is  a  singularity which is  surrounded  by  a band  of  closed orbits. for  quadratic  vector  fields  they  are  classified at [this  paper.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246484433_Integrability_of_plane_quadratic_vector_fields)

The  motivation for  this  post is  mentioned in   [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648)

**Remark:**  The initial motivation is mentioned in [page 3, item 5 of  this  arxiv note.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507516)

Answer (score 1):

## Note:

Befor posting this answer at Aug 2017, I had computed 2 times, carefully so I am sure that the curvature was not identically zero.

---

The quadratic system $y\partial_x -(x+x^2)\partial_y$ has a  center at the  origin. But  the   curvature of the  metric  associated to the  frame described in the question is  not  identically zero. I  computed it and substituted   point $x=1,y=0$ at the  curvature,  the result was non zero.

---

**Remark:** This  enable  us  to  construct a  non flat  metric  on the  cylinder such that the  cylinder  is  foliated  by  closed  geodescis with the same  length, a  non  flat  analogy of the  standard  flat  structure of the  cylinder:  We  count a  deleted neighborhood of the  origin as a topological  cylinder. Now $d\theta.X=1$ implies that all closed geodesics  have the  same  lenght $2\pi.$ Here  $X$ is  $X=V/\psi(V)$  with notations as in the question.