# An explicit formula for a flat metric compatible to certain polynomial vector field with center

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Let  $X$ be  the  following  vector  field  on the  plane:

$$\begin{cases} x'=y\\ y'=-x-x^3\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;(X)$$

The  vector  field $ (X)$ has  a non  isochronous  center  at  the  origin.The proof  is  given in Remark $2$  below. The  punctured plane  is filled  with periodic orbits  of  $X$. The  vector  field  is  geodesible  on the  punctured plane, in the  sense that there  is a Riemannian  metric such that  solutions  of  $X$  are  geodesics  of  the  metric. The  reason of  geodesibility  of  $X$ is  explained  for  some  [similar  system  in this  post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648). In fact the  $1\_$ form  $\psi=d\theta $  works  for  this  vector  field  $X$.That  is  $d\psi=0$  and $\psi(X)>0$. This  is equivalent  to  geodesibility in dimension $2$.

> Question:  What is  an  explicit  flat  Riemannian  metric  such that the  trajectories  of  $X$ are  unparametrized  geodesics?

**Remark 1**  Note that  because of  the  following interesting  comment  of  Prof. Goodwillie  we  should  not expect  that $X$  has a constant  length,  since  the  center  is  not  isochronous

[Extension of a vector field to an orthonormal frame for a flat metric](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278166/extension-of-a-vector-field-to-an-orthonormal-frame-for-a-flat-metric/278173#comment685996_278173)

**Remark 2:**  The period  is  not  a  constant  for  periodic  orbits  surrounding the  origin. A  proof   can  be  given  as follows:

If  we compute the  integral of signed  curvature along  a  closed orbit of  period $T$, we obtain $2\pi=T+\int_0^T \frac{y^2(t)x^2(t)}{y^2(t)+(x(t)+x^3(t))^2}dt$, using  Gauss Bonnete theorem. Since  the  integrant of  the  latter  integral  is positive  and  tends  zero when   closed orbits tend origin , then  period  $T$ should  depend  on choosing the  periodic orbits, namely the  period $T$ can not  be  a  constant. So  the  center is  not  isochronous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the metric doesn't have to extend to the origin, take the flat metric
$$
g = \frac{\bigl(\mathrm{d}\left(x\sqrt{1+x^2/2}\right)\bigr)^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2}{x^2+x^4/2+y^2}.
$$
The level curves $x^2+x^4/2+y^2 = r^2$ are geodesics for the metric, and these are the integral curves of the vector field $X$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Bryant. Thanks  for  this example  of  flat  metric adapted  to the  vector  field  in the question.