# Isochronization of quadratic vector fields with center

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

What is a classification of all quadratic vector fields

$$\begin{cases}
x'=P(x,y)\\
y'=Q(x,y)
\end{cases}\qquad (V)$$
with  a  center  at origin such that $$\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)}\right)V\qquad(V')$$  has  an isochronous center  at $(0,0)$.

Here $P,Q$  are  degree  $2$ polynomials.

In  particular does $y\partial_x-(x+x^2)\partial_y$ satisfy the  above  property?

The  motivations are  mentioned in the  following  very helpful comment   by  Prof. Goodwillie  and the next two  posts. The  role of  isochronous center is very essential. We realize of this importance after  this very helpful comment.

[Extension of a vector field to an orthonormal frame for a flat metric](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278166/extension-of-a-vector-field-to-an-orthonormal-frame-for-a-flat-metric/278173#comment685996_278173)

[A curvature description for center condition for quadratic vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277481/a-curvature-description-for-center-condition-for-quadratic-vector-field?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[An explicit formula for a flat metric compatible to certain polynomial vector field with center](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279625/an-explicit-formula-for-a-flat-metric-compatible-to-certain-polynomial-vector-fi)

Answer (score 1):

The rescalling $(V')$ of $(V)$ as described in the question has always an isochronous center when $(V)$ is a quadratic system with center.

The reason is that  $d\theta(V')=1$ where $d\theta=(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})(ydx-xdy)$.

**Remark:** The  same  argument as  above  can be  applied to  show  the following:

> Let $V$ be  an arbitrary quadratic  vector  field on the  plane and $(V')$ be  the  corresponding rescalling as in the  question. (We no longer  assume  that $V$  has necessarily   a  center).  Then  all  closed orbits or  limit  cycles  of  $V'$ which surround the  origin have  the  same  length provided we choose a  Riemannian metric whose frame  is  in the  form  $\{V', f(x\partial_x+y\partial_y)\}$  where  $f$  is  an  arbitrary  positive  smooth function.