# A foliation of the cylinder by closed geodesics of the same length when the metric is complete but non flat

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, closed-geodesic

Is  there  a  **complete** Riemannian metric  on the cylinder such  that the metric  is  **not  flat** but  the  cylinder is  foliated by  closed geodesics with the same  length?

A  possibility non  complete  metric with the  above properties is introduced in the  "Remark" of the following answer:

[A curvature description for center condition for quadratic vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277481/a-curvature-description-for-center-condition-for-quadratic-vector-field/278766#278766)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard non-flat metric on a torus $T^2$ is foliated by closed geodesics. It can be unwrapped to give an example of what you want.

Specifically, let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be the standard generators for $\pi_1(T^2)$, where there is a foliation of $T^2$ by closed geodesics freely homotopic to $\gamma_1$ (but there isn't one for $\gamma_2$). The covering space $\mathbb{R}^2 / <\!\!\gamma_1\!\!> \to T^2$ is a complete cylinder foliated by closed geodesics that isn't flat.

Comment: +1 and thank you for  your  very interesting  answer.  I am thinking to the "complete part of the  metric. as you indicated in your answer. BTW you are very well come to MO!

Comment: Implicitly, I mean that the cylinder should be endowed with the covering metric, which makes it complete. Of course, every compact Riemannian manifold is complete, and every cover of a complete manifold is complete.