# Cohomology of invariant differential forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cohomology, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $\varphi:M\rightarrow M$ a diffeomorphism. The invariant differential forms
$$
\Omega^{k}_{inv}(M)=\{\alpha\in\Omega^{k}(M):\varphi^{*}\alpha=\alpha\}
$$
form a subcomplex $(\Omega_{inv}(M),d)$ of the de Rham complex. Denote by $H_{inv}(M)$ its cohomology.

**Question:** Is there an example where the map $H^{1}_{inv}(M)\rightarrow H^{1}(M)$ is not injective?

It seems like the map is injective when forms can be averaged with respect to $\varphi$ in some way. For instance if $\varphi$ has finite order, or more generally if $\varphi$ is an isometry for some Riemannian metric $g$, in which case one can average over the closure $\overline{\{\varphi^{n}\}}$ in the compact Lie group $Isom(M,g)$. But I think there should be an example where the map is not injective.

Comment: If you allow non-compact manifolds, it seems to me that the diffeomorphism $x \mapsto x+1$ of $\mathbb{R}$ should provide a counterexample.

Comment: Is this the same question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294918/counterexample-showing-that-g-invariant-de-rham-cohomology-different-from-cohomo?rq=1

Comment: @ChrisMcDaniel Not really. My question is indeed about a specific group action $(G=\mathbb{Z})$, but the counterexample to injectivity in your link concerns a non-compact manifold (essentially what Francesco Polizzi says in his comment above)

Comment: @studiosus yes but he also says that the cohomology of invariant differential forms is isomorphic to the invariant cohomology classes, which does indeed inject into the cohomology ring.

Comment: @ChrisMcDaniel Only when the group acting is a compact Lie group, isn't it? This doesn't apply to the case $G=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing: any $\phi$-invariant exact
1-form is a differential of $\phi$-invariant function.

Indeed, let $\alpha$ be an exact $\phi$-invariant
form, $\alpha=df$, where $f$ is not $\phi$-invariant.
Then $d(\phi^* f -f)=0$, hence
$\phi^* f = f + C$, where $C$ is a constant.
This gives $\sup f = \sup \phi^* f = \sup f + C$, which is
a contradiction.

For higher cohomology I think there are some examples.