# A non integrable distribution which is totally geodesic

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, foliations

Is there a non integrable  $2$ dimensional  distribution $D$ of a $3$ dimensional  Riemannian manifold such that the distribution is totally geodesic in the following sense:

Every geodesic whose tangent vector of its intitial  point is tangent to the distribution then the tangent vector  at all its points is tangent to $D$, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the standard contact structure on the unit three-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4 = \mathbb{C}^2$, for instance. The Legendrian great circles are the intersections of the sphere with the Lagrangian two-planes.

Comment: Thank you  and  +1 for your answer.  To be  honest I  need  some  background to  understand  your  answer. I think that the  wikipedia  link in the other answer can  help me  to understand the details. I would  appreciate if  you read  my  comment to  "mathematician", the  other  answer er. Thanks  again for  your  attention to my question.

Comment: I  am  sorry  if my question is  elementary.

Comment: @AliTaghavi. it is a good question. Some years ago Patrick Massot, a student of Giroux, did some nice work on this: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.gt/1513800108

Comment: Thanks again for your attention to my question and very interesting answer and  your reference to the paper of Patrick Massot.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the distribution which is the kernel of the one-form $dz - y dx$. This is the standard example of a contact structure on $\mathbb{R}^3$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry .

Comment: Thank you and  +1 for  your answer. Did  I  understand your  answer  correctly: Let $\alpha$ be  a  contact  structure  with the  unique  Reeb vector  field  $R$(as I learn from the  link in your answer). Let  $X$  be the  tangent vector  field to  our geodesic. We  consider a  Riemannian metric whose frame is $\{RD,\}$  where  $D=\ker \alpha$.  Then  we  have  to prove  $X.R$  is  identically  zero  provided it is  zero  at the  initial point. But  I  can not prove this Sould I  understand from your  answer the  following: If  we  have a  contact  structure $\alpha$  with the Reeb field R

Comment: and  a  Riemannian metric  $g$  such that  $R$ is $g-$ perpendicular to $\ker \alpha$ then the later distribution is  totally  geodesic in the  sense of my question?

Comment: I  am  sorry  if  my  question is  elementary.

Comment: In fact  I  computed $X.(<X.R>)=<\nabla_X X,.R>+<\nabla_X R,X>=<\nabla_X R,X>$  but why the later is  zero?  As  I  learned the  Reeb vector  field  from the  link of  your  answer  I realize that the  Reeb vector  field satisfies the  conditions  of  propostion 6.8  mentioned in this  answer  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648

Comment: I'm not a Riemannian geometer, so I don't know if I can respond directly to your comment. But you might try looking up first the Chow-Rashevskii theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%E2%80%93Rashevskii_theorem ). Existence of geodesics comes from the Hopf-Rinow theorem. You can argue that a geodesic must be a.e. tangent to the horizontal distribution.

Comment: Thanks a  lot  for  your attention and  your very  helpful  comment.