# unique continuation in a disk

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

Let $D$ be the unit disc in $\mathbb R^2$ centered at the origin. Let $w \in C^{\infty}_c(D)$ satisfy
$$ (1-r^2)^2\Delta w +w =0.$$
Prove that $w \equiv 0$.

Comment: You can expand $w(r,\varphi) = \sum w_n(r) e^{in\varphi}$, and then the $w_n(r)$ satisfy ODEs and $w_n=0$ near $r=1$, so $w_n\equiv 0$.

Comment: For what it's worth, Ali, if you are specifically looking for a 'unique continuation'-type argument, I believe this is addressed in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392276/differential-inequalities-under-which-a-flat-function-must-be-identically-zero/392287#392287) in a more general setting.